# Hyperledger-Fabric network.sh not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When I run the network.sh up command  I get as result " ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer0.org1.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peer0.org1.example.com (9dace0451ce23579ca2750b24f788c04c566e9007534c6cf6e472c0bd204ba28): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:7051: bind: address already in use"

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my thought, there were 2 cases:

1. It was some other process that is also using port 7051. So you have to remove that particular process as per your os that will help you in solving the problem.
2. As in other cases, it mostly is the same container running at some other instance. In that case, verify using `docker ps` It shows a list of containers, and if the same containers running in other directories and then try running again at other places where the container name is the same. for that, you have to remove all the containers.

Command:

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all running containers and re-run the script.